# how to make dynamic pager for jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In JqGrid how do we set the rowList according to total records returned? By default its set as `rowList:[10,20,30],`

I want to set it as per no of records e.g if total records returned is 50 my rowList should be 
`rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],` and in case of 20 records it should be `rowList:[10,20],`

I can see the total records are returned in JSON object which I can get as

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');

var records = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
console.log('recods:',records);
jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridParam', {rowList: [10,20,30,50]});
var rowList = jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowList');
console.log('rowList:',rowList);
// Above code works
jQuery(grid_selector).trigger('reloadGrid'); 
// Reload grid does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get records through:

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
```

then:

```
 function make_array(count)
{
var record_count=count;
var record_array=[]

for(i=10;i<=record_count;i+=10)
{
record_array.push(i);
}

return "rowlist:["+record_array.valueOf()+"]";
}
```

Example:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y0kmo6ss/1/

Comment: I tried to set the param after grid load as jQuery(grid_selector).jqGrid('setGridParam', {rowList: [10,20,30,50]}).trigger('reloadGrid'); but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. If you want that jqGrid displays **all records on one page** you need just set `rowNum` value to large enough value (for example `rowNum: 10000`). The values displayed in the select built based on `rowList` allows *the user* to change the page size. If the user change the value then new request to the server fill be made (if you don't use local `datatype`), the `rowNum` value will be changed and the page of data will be reloaded from the server.

So you could probably just use large enough value of `rowNum`. You can consider to *remove* unneeded elements of the pager (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager#properties)). If you want to provide the user the possibility to display *all* data you need just provide large enough value in the `rowList` array. For example

```
rowNum: 10,
pager: "#mypager",
rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 10000]
```

You can makes the user the look of large value "10000" more comfortable by executing the following line

```
$("#mypager option[value=10000]").text("All");
```

`mypager` is the id of the `pager`. The above line changes just **the text** of the option in the select. So the `<option>` with `value="10000"` will have the text `All` instead of `10000`, which is more comfortable for users.